# Any way to tell in Salesforce how much CPU a specific Process Builder/Flow is using?

Tags: performance

We are running into CPU time limit exceeded errors in Salesforce. The org does have multiple Process Builders/Flows on the Case object. For a particular Case insert operation, I pulled an analysis from the dev console and it shows that Workflow (Process Builders/Flows/Workflow rules, etc) is using an ungodly amount of CPU (see below screenshot):

[image]

Is there any way to tell *which* Process Builders/Flows/Workflow rules are eating up the most CPU? Or should I start throwing darts at this problem by disabling pieces of Workflow 1 by 1 to narrow it down?

Edit: I looked at the performance/execution stack in Analysis perspective but it isn't telling me which pieces of Workflow are using the most CPU. See below screenshot:
[image]

I drilled down pretty far in the Workflow tree and I'm seeing a bunch of n/a's (see below screenshot). Not sure why it's not telling me how much CPU each node is consuming.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Open a Perspective that includes the Stack Tree, and you can open the various nodes to examine how much time is spent per flow. Click on Debug > Switch Perspective... > **Analysis (Predefined)**. In the upper-left corner, you can expand the entire transaction and view its subcomponents. Navigate to where your Flows are (they should be under Workflow, I believe), and you can see how long each one took. It should be pretty easy to figure things out from there. If you have this much automation going on, it's probably time to see if you can move some or all of these to Before Save Flows, which have as much as 10 times better performance than Record Update Flows.

Comment: Hey sfdcfox, I was able to locate the Stack Trees (execution and performance). I expanded the nodes but they're only accommodating for a small portion of the CPU used (I updated my question, check out the additional screenshots to see what i mean). Strange that they are not giving me the full picture.

Comment: @ronnie777 You might need to adjust the debug log levels. I'd have to set up an example, I'll see if I can get something for you.

Comment: @ronnie777. Maybe this Apex Log Analyzer Helps 
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/12/find-problems-faster-with-the-apex-log-analyzer.html

Comment: @sfdcfox which debug log levels should I adjust? When I ran the analysis, I had every log level cranked up to the highest except for 'nba'.

Comment: @HR that Apex Log Analyzer tool is great. I wasn't aware of its existence. Thanks for sharing