# To disable an apex trigger from managed package

Tags: apex, trigger

I am helping the release engineering to team to update the records in one of our sfdc sandbox environment. However, for a object named 'case', no matter how small the bulk batch size I set, I always get the following error message:

```
    "CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY:csmrgp.CaseTrigger: System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded:--"
```

So i drill down and found this issue is related to a trigger which is called 'csmrgp.CaseTrigger'. However, this trigger is related to a managed packaged installed in the system. Seems there is no way for me to disable it.

currently I have to do the regular update to avoid this error, but this object has over 8 million records, doing the regular update will take forever. Anyone has any idea how that I can disable this trigger or anyway that i can expedite my update process?

Comment: Note that CPU limits are cumulative across all code. Just because it's happening in that trigger doesn't mean it's necessarily the problem. Try using the [analysis view](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/328651/2984) to verify if this trigger is *actually* the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately we cannot disable triggers created by managed package. It sucks as we run into this issue while data-loading where we want automations to be disabled.

Only thing you can do is reach out to the package author and ask them to provide a mechanism to disable-automations in their package. Probably they will create a custom setting or field in User object, when set, their code can skip automations.